# AX 2012 Labels in SSRS Unbound Parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008, report, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

I have a SSRS report in AX 2012 with a parameter, where Values is set to "Unbound Values" (Non-queried). In the popup for adding values, I have added a couple of lines with a value and a label like the following:

```
Value: MainAccountId,
Label: =Labels!@SYS135766
```

But when I preview (or run the report from AX after deploying), the text "Labels!@SYS135766" is shown as label in the dropdown on the dialog (instead of "Main account").

I have also tried with "Labels!@SYS135766" and "@SYS135766", but with no luck.

Does anyone know how to get the label ID translated to a text using unbound parameter values?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but still posting the possible answer hoping that it can help.

Cite from a [post](http://wek2nam.blogspot.com/2012/09/dynamics-ax-2012-report-labels-does-not.html) by Namukoa Isaac:

Reasons for the problem:

> - You have moved your AX service account from AX domain account from AX domain admin group
> - You have changed your SSRS service account password.
>
> Solutions:
>
> > 1. From the Start menu, point to All Programs, click the SQL Server folder, click theConfiguration Tools folder, and then click Reporting Services Configuration Manager.
> > 2. In Reporting Services Configuration Manager click Connect and then click Service Account.
> > 3. Set the password and then click Apply. The account and password should be the same as the Microsoft Dynamics AX proxy account.
> > 4. System will ask you to backup your encrytion key, and then will some settings on the backhand.
> > 5. Now Click the ServerName/MSSQLSERVER on the left top of the reporting server and then click Stop. Then click Start to restart the server. Always check with the SQL administrator and make sure no other users are connected to the server before you restart the server.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for trying to answer my question. However, I do not think that it would solve the issue, as any other label was working perfectly well as the time.